# How to go back to ipython in mac terminal after using the help function

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

After doing `help(my_list.append)`. IPython shows this below,

```
Help on method_descriptor:

append(...)
    L.append(object) -> None -- append object to end
~~
(END)
```

How do I go back to IPython? o I have to close the shell everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow button (top and bottom) to jump into your previous commands.

Answer (score 0):

`q` to quit help. `h` to see other key options.

In ipython I usually use `?` and `??` after the function to get help or code. Same quit keystroke.

At least on my Linux OS, the `h` help shows keystrokes for the shell pager `less`

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped! Such a simple stroke of the key helped sort my frustration of figuring this out for hours!